# docker compose error "Connection to localhost:5432 refused."

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I run my docker-compose, I face this error:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8N95.png)

```
app         | 2021-09-23 11:52:51.860 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
app         |
app         | org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
app         |   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
app         |   at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
app         |   at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
```

I tried to change the url in my application.properties file and the error is the same.
This is my application.properties file:
[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wreb4.png)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/employees
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8086
## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

`
This is my Dockerfile:
[Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udIUx.png)

```
from openjdk:8
copy ./target/springboot2-postgresql-jpa-hibernate-crud-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar employee-jdbc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","employee-jdbc-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

And this is my docker-compose:
[docker-compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rg2m6.png)

```
version: "3"
services:
 postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5430
    ports:
      - 5430:5430
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=employees

# APP*****************************************
 app:
    image: app
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: app
    expose:
      - 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=employees
      - POSTGRES_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/employees


volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Comment: Please post your files as text rather than images.

Comment: From the error message it looks like it's trying to connect to `localhost:5432`. Your connection string says `postgres:5432` (which is correct). Are you using an old image? Try and build the `app` image and try again.

Comment: I am not using an old image but I'm using jar file of the old build (where I was using localhost:5432) so even when I change my connection string the docker container is always using the localhost:5432

Comment: Ah, ok. So you need to build the .jar file and then the docker image

Comment: When I build the .jar file with postgres:5432 it doesn't work, It returns JDBC failure connection. I think that I need to build the app in the Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Can you run this command to check

`sudo lsof -n -u postgres |grep LISTEN or sudo netstat -ltnp | grep postgres`

should show the TCP/IP addresses and ports PostgreSQL is listening on

It can be postgres is already running and your image is not running using docker. Maybe killing the process will help you if it is already running.

Comment: This is the output:                                                                                                            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1476/postmaster
tcp6       0      0 ::1:5432                :::*                    LISTEN      1476/postmaster
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27874    1476/postmaster      /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     27872    1476/postmaster      /var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432

Comment: Postgress is running on port 5432. And in docker-compose, we are using PORT 5430.